# Decrypt connection string section in other machines

Tags: c#, windows, encryption, app-config

Since I have database passwors and SMTP settings on settings file, I'd like that sensative data from being edited/see by not authorizated uers.

I was going to use the asp tool to encrypt my app.config (I rename it to web.config then back to app.config) using the `aspnet_regiis` tool. It seemd to work fine, until I learnt it uses some kind of mac/key to prevent it from being decrypted in others machines. So is there any way to make the file decrypted in any machine?

Comment: With regards to database passwords, if possible consider using windows authentication.... though it's not simple and not always possible (depending on the database platform)

Comment: It's a MySQL database. How would that Windows authentication work?

Comment: I'm willing to roll my own encrypted configuration file to store that sensitve information and after all, the key to decrypt that same settings file must be in the source code, easily seen on .NET disassembler (I don't know how much a IL obfuscator can help at this)

Comment: I've never used it but you could try this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/windows-authentication-plugin.html in SQL Server the way it works is in our connection you don't specify user/password you just say 'use the current windows user to connect'. There are things to consider though.... for example if you set it up this way the windows user could also connect directly to the database through some other tool